# Using data return from sharepoint assetimagepicker

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

I'm working with Sharepoint 2007. I use the built in AssetImagePicker.aspx and I need to retrieve the image url from that page and use it in my custom webpart.
I want to run my javascript code to run when clicking the OK button of the AssetImagePicker.aspx but I can't find a way to do that.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question properly, and I know nothing about Sharepoint (and AssetImagePicker.aspx) but it sounds like you want to add an event handler to the OK button: to run a function when the click event of the button is fired.

You can either code event handling yourself (see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/dhtml_events.asp) or [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) for examples of this) or (probably better) use a library like [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp).